# Identifying folder with name as largest number in the directory

Tags: bash, filenames

there is a directory which contains folders named with numbers, i've to find the folder with largest number in that directory.
This is the script i've written to find that folder:

```
files='ls path/'
var=0

for file in $files
do
    echo $file
    tmp=$((file-"0"))
    if [ $tmp -gt $var ]
    then 
        var=$tmp
    fi
done

echo $var
```

But it's not working. It gives below error after invoking the script using command `sudo ./restore2.sh`.

```
ls
path/
./restore2.sh: line 6: path/: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/")
0
```

Comment: You are calculating in `$((file-"0"))` the difference of the content of the variable `file` and zero. What's the purpose of this? `file` does not contain even a number, but the string `path/`, as you can see from the output you posted. BTW, if you really pasted the full error message here, it means that you are not running bash, because if you were, the error message would contain the word _bash_.

Comment: @user1934428 I wanted to convert it to integer, so i subtracted 0 in the form of string from the variable file. or do i have to subtract a empty string from it? and i've made a bash script to execute it.

Comment: Why there are so many downvotes? I asked a question and shown tried approach, i think i followed the protocol, but still received downvotes.

Comment: The downvotes express that you did not show much effort. Indeed: (1) Although your own debugging output, which you concluded, exhibits at least one error in the program (the fact that `file` does not contain any numeric information), you don't bother about it and just asked others to debug it for you. (2) While you show the script, you don't show how you actually invoke the script.

Comment: @user1934428 sorry i couldn't understand the first one, but i'll surely correct the second.

Comment: What is so difficult to understand? If you want to do mathematics, both operands must be numbers, and the output you provide by yourself,  clearly shows that one operand is not a number!

Comment: yes of course, the filename `file` is  of string type and the question is to convert that to integer  and find greatest such value, that's why OP is subtracting "0" from it, here  `tmp=$((file-"0"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
files=`ls path/`
var=0
for file in $files
do
    echo $file
    tmp=$((file-"0"))
    if [ $tmp -gt $var ]
    then 
       var=$tmp
    fi
done

echo $var
```

there's a backtick here:  `ls path/` instead of single or double-quotes.
I've only corrected this statement and it worked. and notice to add `#!/bin/bash` at the top of the script. This will tell your system to run the script in a bash shell.

Comment: Thanks, it works. but without  `#!/bin/bash`, still it was giving correct output.

Answer (score 1):

You're using single quotes instead of backticks `files='ls path/'`. It's trying to use it as a literal string instead of evaluating it.
Also, for that specific task, you can just do:

```
ls test | awk '{if($1 > largest){largest = $1}} END{print largest}'
```

To have it a bit simpler.

Comment: Hi, what's the `largest` and `$1` here? how are you intializing it? can you please post a  detailed code.

Comment: `$1` is the first space separated value for each line. `largest` is automatically initialized by AWK when using it. AWK is a pattern-action language, here the patterns are "run if number is bigger" and "run at the end". AWK is very worth learning for quick one liners. @user14602825

Answer (score 0):

Use find instead:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -regextype "posix-extended" -regex "^.*[[:digit:]]+.*$" | sort -n | tail -1
```

Set the maxdepth to 1 to check for directories within this directory only and no deeper. Set the regular expression type to posix-extended and search for all directories that have one or more digits. Print the result and order through sort before taking the largest one with tail -1.

Answer (score 0):

Does `path/` have any files in it? It looks like it's empty.
You *should* be getting a completely different complaint...

You don't want the path info in the filename. Rather than strip it with `${file##*/}`, just go there and use non-path'd names.

An adaptation using your own logic as its base -

```
cd /whatever/path/                     # go where the files are
var=-1                                 # initialize comparator 
for file in [0-9]*                     # each entry that starts with a digit
do [[ "$file" =~ [^0-9] ]] && continue # skip any file with nondigit contents
   [[ -f "$file" ]]        || continue # only process plain files
   (( file > var )) && var=$file       # remember largest seen 
done
echo $var                              # report largest
```

If you are sure there will be no negative numbered filenames, this should do it.
If there can be valid negatives, then your initialization needs to be appropriately lower, and the exclusion of nondigits should include the minus sign, as well as the list of files to select.

Note that this [doesn't parse `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and doesn't require piping through a `sort` or spawning any other processes -- it's all handled in the `bash` interpreter and should be pretty efficient.

If you are sure of your data, and know there aren't any negatives or files named just `0` or non-plain-file entries in the directory that match the `[0-9]*` pattern, you can simplify it to just

```
cd /whatever/path/                     # go where the files are
for file in [0-9]*; do (( file > var )) && var=$file; done
echo $var                              # report largest
```

As an aside, if you wanted to preserve the "make a list first" logic, you should still NOT use `ls`. Use an array.

```
cd /wherever/your/files/are/
files=( [0-9]* )
for file in "${files[@]}"
do : ...
```